# Unable to send POST request using Flask test client

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, testdriven.io

I'm following the `TestDriven.io` course, after setting up restful routes I encounter this error even after adding the route handler in `project/api/users.py`:

```
test_app_is_development (test_config.TestDevelopmentConfig) ... ok
test_app_is_production (test_config.TestProductionConfig) ... ok
test_app_is_testing (test_config.TestTestingConfig) ... ok
test_add_user (test_users.TestUserService)
Ensure a new user can be added to the database ... ERROR
test_users (test_users.TestUserService)
Ensure the /ping  route behaves correctly. ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: test_add_user (test_users.TestUserService)
Ensure a new user can be added to the database
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1283, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 590, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'now'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/project/tests/test_users.py", line 22, in test_add_user
    response = self.client.post(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1016, in post
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 222, in open
    return Client.open(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 970, in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ.copy(), buffered=buffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 861, in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1096, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 468, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 89, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 583, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/project/api/users.py", line 28, in post
    db.session.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 163, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1042, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 504, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2523, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2664, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2624, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 586, in execute
    persistence.save_obj(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 239, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1135, in _emit_insert_statements
    result = cached_connections[connection].execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1020, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1133, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1323, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1517, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1283, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 590, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'now'
[SQL: INSERT INTO users (username, email, active, created_date) VALUES (%(username)s, %(email)s, %(active)s, %(created_date)s) RETURNING users.id]
[parameters: {'username': 'michael', 'email': 'michael@mherman.org', 'active': True, 'created_date': <sqlalchemy.sql.functions.now at 0x7f5369329f40; now>}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.307s

FAILED (errors=1)
<unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=5 errors=1 failures=0>
```

As you can see the error has to do with the `self.client.post` request done in this function:

```
def test_add_user(self):
        """Ensure a new user can be added to the database"""
        with self.client:
            response = self.client.post(
                '/users',
                data=json.dumps({
                    'username': 'michael',
                    'email': 'michael@mherman.org'
                }),
                content_type='application/json',
            )
            print (response)
            data = json.loads(response.data.decode())
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
            self.assertIn('michael@mherman.org was added!', data['message'])
            self.assertIn('success', data['status'])
```

Everything seems correct in the logic and syntax of the code but I can't figure out why the test isn't passing?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the error log, the problem is in the INSERT INTO statement. The `created_date` parameter is not a date but a function `sqlalchemy.sql.functions.now`. It looks like you forgot to call it.

Comment: Thank you very much @timur-mukhametulin. I actually forgot to call it.